# F# - warning that I am not declaring type parameters explicitly

Tags: generics, types, f#

Given:

```
type Service = Object
type Services = ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Service>
```

Why does this:

```
// If we use this form, we get a compiler warning:
type GetService<'T> = Services -> 'T
let GetService:GetService<'T> = fun services ->
    services.[typeof<'T>] :?> 'T
```

produce the warning:

"The method or function 'GetService' should not be given explicit type arguments because it does not declare its type parameters explicity."

But this does not:

```
let GetService<'T> (services : Services) =
    services.[typeof<'T>] :?> 'T
```

Example usage:

```
let someService = services |> GetService<SomeServiceType>
```

If I want to correct the first version so as not to get the warning, how would I change the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give it a type parameter, as the error message suggests. This should work:

```
let GetService<'T> : GetService<'T> = fun services ->
    services.[typeof<'T>] :?> 'T
```